# Is it possible to execute a method once before a single but parameterized test?

Tags: java, testng

So I have Selenium tests that use TestNG to test UI, but right now I'm struggling with a problem : how can I execute a specific method **only once** before a parameterized test ?
I have a parameterized test like this :

```
@Test(dataProvider="myProvider")
public void testMyThingToTest() {
   // Things to test in here
}
```

My parameterized test works great and gets executed once for each parameter given. Now I have a initialization that is common to all my instances of my parameterized test, so I would like it to be ran **only once**, not before **every instance of the parameterized test**...
If I do something like using @BeforeTest or @BeforeMethod :

```
@BeforeMethod
public void initialization() {
    // The initialization phase here...
}
```

The init method is run before every test... any idea how to achieve that ?
The purpose of this is to avoid doing some overwhelming job for each parameter, because my initialization takes something like 30 sec, and I have 7-8 parameters for my test, so I would rather have an initialization time of **30sec * 1** rather than **30sec * 8**

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to execute a method only once for all tests that are in you test class.

TestNG provide an annotation for that `@BeforeClass`: Annotates methods that will be run before the first method on the current test class is run.

You can find an example at http://java.dzone.com/articles/testng-beforeclass-annotation

Comment: Not really, I would like to run the initialization method only once before a specific (parameterized) test, but before all tests. Well, I guess I could make sure that the parameterized test is running first in the test class using priorities, but it's a bit dirty...

Comment: I don't quite understand, if you use @BeforeClass it would run just once.  Are your tests spread across classes?  If you have more tests in your classes and you do not want to run for all, then put the beforeclass in a group same as your test and run only the group. Would that help?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@BeforeSuite
public void initialization() {
    // Init suite
}
```

If you want other scenarios. Pick annotation with following priority:
@BeforeSuite > @BeforeTest > @BeforeClass > @BeforeMethod

Answer (score 1):

call function in dataprovider

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] FeederOfResponseCodes()
{
        initialization();

        return new Object[][]
        {
        };
}
```